Why is File Explorer (Win 10) closing randomly?
Every so often, my Windows 10 File Explorer - the thing you explore files with - closes on its own. As in it's no longer open. On my computer. This mostly seems to happen after I've stepped away from the PC and the screen auto-lock has happened, which means I have to sign in. With a password.
Any idea what might cause this odd behavior, meaning not normal behavior?
There is no more detail.

Is this happening when File Explorer is showing the contents of network drives? If so, see the answers in File Explorer Closes Randomly?

It will close when the location it was showing is no longer available. This can be a network drive that got disconnected or a usb drive that was removed from the system, etc. It can also happen if you view a folder that is removed from another location. For example, you view the content of a network drive, and someone else renames or moves that folder. And not to forget, if your computer locks and goes into standby, you lose network connectivity.
